How to calculate correlation between two distribution in Bayesian statistics?
I am trying to calculate the correlation between two distributions (let’s call them height and weight). I know how to calculate a simple Pearson correlation using a frequentist approach: calculate the covariance, calculate the covariance matrix and then divide it by sd(x)×sd(y)
The standard formula for covariance can be calculated as:Covariance formula 1
or via the correlation coefficient  as:
Covariance formula 2

The first question I have is whether it’s appropriate to calculate the mean as in the frequentist method. Would it be correct to obtain two separate posteriors (for weight and height), then calculate covariance and correlation using the first equation?

Is it possible to treat ρ as a posterior? Should I first obtain posteriors for height and weight, then calculate ρ afterward?


My code
I'm trying to use PyMC, but in my model, I can only obtain an estimate for one distribution. The prior and posterior ρ differs, but I don't understand why.
high_values = df['high'].values #no NaN 
weight_values = df["weight"].values

with pm.Model() as model:
    rho_transformed = pm.Beta("rho_transformed", alpha=2, beta=2)
    rho = pm.Deterministic("rho", rho_transformed * 2 - 1)  # Map back to [-1, 1]
    
    # Define mean 
    mu_high = pm.NegativeBinomial("mu_1", mu=mu_1, alpha = 4) #t or poisson ...
    mu_weight = pm.NegativeBinomial('mu_2', mu=mu_2, alpha=shape) #negBin
    # Difine std
    sigma_high = pm.HalfNormal("sigma_1", sigma=1)
    sigma_weight = pm.HalfNormal("sigma_2", sigma=1)

    cov_matrix = pm.math.stack([
        [sigma_high**2, rho * sigma_high * sigma_weight],
        [rho * sigma_high * sigma_weight, sigma_weight**2]
    ]) #is it correct in bayes?


    # Observed data
    observed_data = np.column_stack([high_values, weight_values]).astype("float64")

    mu_value = pt.as_tensor_variable([mu_high, mu_weight]) #thats a very strange thing
    observed = pm.MvNormal("observed", mu=mu_value, cov=cov_matrix, observed=observed_data) #multivariate normal distribution
    
    # Prior and Posterior Predictive Checks
    prior_samples = pm.sample_prior_predictive(draws=1000)
    posterior_samples = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace)
    
    # Run the sampler
    trace = pm.sample(1000, return_inferencedata=True) #Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) sampling to draw samples from the posterior distribution of each parameter. 

You could call prior_samples.prior['rho'] and trace.posterior['rho'] to check that they differs:)

Interesting question, but it's off topic here; try [stats.SE]. Mutual information is the generalization of correlation to arbitrary distributions, although it is generally pretty difficult to calculate. Sounds like you're not actually working with height and weight; if so, my advice is to say exactly what you are working with, since the best approach will depend strongly on the joint distribution involved.
